# Manually Setting Interface metric priority of Network Adapters not preferring lower metric route on Windows

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, cisco-vpn-client, split-tunnel

After Connecting to Cisco VPN AnyConnect, Now I have two network interfaces  having set same default routes, but with different metric values. Even after manually changing/raising the metric value of one default route(i.e. imposed by VPN from metric value 2 to 1000) to give preference to my default route(metric value 26), it's still preferring the VPN one(instead of raising the VPN route metric value from 2 to 1000 as you can see in route print output)

Here is my route print output:

```
route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...90 4c e5 58 9f 09 ......Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
 20...00 05 9a 3c 7a 00 ......Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual M
                              niport Adapter for Windows
===========================================================================

 IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
  Active Routes:
  Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
         0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     26
         0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       10.1.105.2   1000
        10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link        10.1.105.2   1255
      10.1.105.2  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.105.2   1255
  10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.105.2   1255
       127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
 127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    164.100.28.5  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     26
 164.100.176.115  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     26
     192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
     192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2     26
     192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
   192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
       224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
       224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.1.105.2   1255
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.105.2   1255
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1     999
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
23     58 ::/0                     On-link
 1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
23    306 2001:0:9d38:6abd:348b:29cb:f5fe:96fd/128
                                On-link
23    306 fe80::348b:29cb:f5fe:96fd/128
                                On-link
 1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
23    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None
```

I doubted of this Persistent route entry block which is there in output above as:

```
Persistent Routes:
    Network Address         Netmask     Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       999
```

But after issuing the below delete route command as:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

Now Persistent route entry has gone,  its displaying as None.

As you see, Even Metric is 26 which is much lower than 1000, it's still following 1000 metric route. What is going on?

```
Network Destination       Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
         0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     26
         0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       10.1.105.2   1000
```

Even I have done the following:
In my Adapter Settings (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections) Advanced Settings Changed the order of the connections so that my connection priority is top on the list over Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

Still If i tracert google.com, still my traffic going over VPN.
Where is the concept of preferring lower cost matrix?
can someone explain to me, what is going over here?

If someone wants to say Cisco AnyConnect Client is playing here behind the scene,

Shall I no more believe on my route print output's?
Shall I no more believe on concept of preferring lower metric value over higher ones?

please, I want to have my doubts clear.

Comment: Did you try flush router cash? `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the configurations on the Cisco VPN device you are connecting to not allowing split tunneling.  When you disconnect from the VPN the traffic likely utilizes your connection.  When you connect to the VPN via the Ciscoanyconnect client, it receives directions from the cisco vpn device to not allow split tuneling, i.e. only allow traffic to come to this device via the tunnel and we will route it from here, so any traffic outside of that remote network is routed from and subjected to, the same security as if you were physically sitting at a location within the network.  This is just an assumption, I am not familiar with the setup of the VPN device you are connecting to.

Comment: I know very well that split tunneling is disabled by admin,  that's why i am looking to modify routes, but cisco Anyconnect client is sitting like watchguard over my pc and reconnects itself whenever i modify routes... How it comes to know about this modification of routes. This client has taken over my admin windows control..I am no more admin..It's like something sitting and reverts back all my modifications...How is it spying over my computer? There must be something it's been doing on my pc for this spying, and not allowing to modify routes.

Comment: forget vpn side, I feel this is not the right way to take over admin control of windows users... How to stop this client from spying on my windows route table?

Comment: @AshishKataria I also second the posit that this is a result of the VPN router.  I'm not familiar with CiscoAnyConnect, so this may not work, but have you looked into the connection settings for the client side of CiscoAnyConnect?  This could be an apples to oranges comparison, but for an example, OpenVPN has a handful of options that can be specified on the client, albeit almost all options must be mirrored between server and client.  Have you reached out to the VPN provider, as that would likely be the most fruitful way of obtaining an answer either way.